# Solve the Differential Equation : $y'' + \frac{L(x)}{2}y = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the $2$nd order differential equation :
>   $$y'' + \frac{L(x)}{2}y = 0  $$

I have been looking at different methods as *known integral*, *variation of parameters*  etc, but I don't know how to go about this equation.

Please help.

Comment: It is in general quite difficult with no known general formula(s).

Comment: Do you know power series methods of evaluating differential equations with variable coefficients?

Comment: If $L$ is an analytic function and you have an IVP then you can obtain a series solution in terms of the coefficients of the series for $L$. But that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a quite difficult problem to proceed with, without knowing $L(x)$, since there isn't a known general formula.

There is a method that can help with differential equations that have a function of $x$, $f(x)$ as a coefficient of the derivatives of the solutions and it's by using power series to determine the solution of differential equations.

The general idea, is that we're looking for a solution of the form :

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n = c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2 + \dots$$

We proceed by substituting this expression into the given differential equation to determine the values of the coefficients $c_0,c_1,c_2,\dots$

You'll have to calculate the derivatives of the series given, so you can plug it in, depending on your given differential equation each time :

$$y'= \sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_nx^{n-1}$$

$$y'' = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nx^{n-2}$$

$$\dots$$

There are many things to look after in such a method and many variations (finding a solution via power series around a specific point, which some times has a big significance). You can read some more stuff [here](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/2233-S99/2233-l24.pdf) .

Comment: Thank you very much every one now I know I need to go into the direction of series solutions.